# How to start and close a console application?

Tags: vb.net, console-application

Console application:

```
    Dim myno As Integer = 1010
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(myno))
    Dim sw As New StreamWriter("filename.txt", True)
    sw.Write(Convert.ToString(myno))
    sw.Flush()
    sw.Close()
    Console.ReadLine()
```

Windows application:

```
    Dim mm As New System.Diagnostics.Process
    Dim info As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(Application.StartupPath & "\ConsoleApplication1.exe")
    mm.StartInfo = info
    mm.Start()
    Dim f As New FileInfo(Application.StartupPath & "\filename.txt")
    Dim s As StreamReader = f.OpenText
    TextBox1.Text = s.ReadToEnd
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Then
        mm.Kill()
    End If
```

However the Console app doesn't write in the textfile and the Windows app starts but won't close.

Comment: Why would the Windows app close, you did not post any code that would cause it to close.  And "C app dont write in textfile" does not provide enough information.  Did it error out, was the file not created, etc.  Details required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are immediately trying to read from the file rather than waiting until the console application is finished writing to the file.  If you have control over the console application, remove that last `ReadLine` so that it closes automatically once it's done.  Then you can wait for the process to end before reading from the file.  If, however, you can't make modifications to the console application, you are going to have to do something more "hacky" such as watching for the file to change, or waiting for a specified period of time and hoping that your wait time is long enough.

Comment: In principle. my consol app read comport and write in textfile but I cant control it.i want to start consoleapp and get value from textfile then close consoleapp.